# Variables names to access nested object keys

Tags: javascript

Apologies if this title makes no sense, but I couldn't find a way to describe this. I have searched a lot but keep getting answers to access a single level.

I have an object:

```
var o = {
    id: 1,
    customer: {
        name: 'Barry Scroggins'
    }
}
```

I have an accessor:

```
var keyName = 'customer'
```

Which I know I can use in the following way to get the customer part of the object:

```
o[keyName] // { name: 'Barry Scroggins' }
```

However, in my application, I would like to access the 'name' portion of the customer object, using a *dynamically created set of variables*. So my application churns out this string:

```
var accessors = 'customer.name';
```

Which I then split at the '.' to get an array of entries, but no matter what I try, I can't access the customer name part directly.

I know I can do it like this: `o['customer']['name']` but I need to build up those keys dynamically and there could be any number of levels to them (i.e. `customer.address.zipcode`)

Is this possible, or is a terrible, horrible way to build things? If so, do you have an alternative?

Comment: Although possible, this is a terrible, horrible way to build things. Put everything in var customer, don't even create var o. Refer to Nina Scholz's answer for those who don't have a more reasonable alternative. The OP does have a better way available though.

Comment: @TurnipEntropy I agree, the whole thing is a mess but almost everything is pooped out of a backend api then dumped into a single template which is used to render a webpage. Although a duplicate, I prefer the answer given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the path and reduce the object.

```js
function getValue(o, path) {
    return path.split('.').reduce(function (o, k) {
        return (o || {})[k];
    }, o);
}

var o = {
        id: 1,
        customer: {
            name: 'Barry Scroggins'
        }
    },
    accessors = 'customer.name';

console.log(getValue(o, accessors));
```